# Angular JS : Failed to instantiate module test due to:

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm running some Javascript inside a HTML file. And I'm trying to use some Angular JS with the function ng-repeat. Each time I run it, I get this error in the console :

```
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

And when I click on the link within the error message in the console, I get this:

`Failed to instantiate module test due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/nomod?p0=test
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:6:425
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:26:270
    at b (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:25:299)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:26:44
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:42:117
    at q (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:7:495)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:41:476)
    at eb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:46:44)
    at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:21:373)
    at Sc (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js:22:179`

Here is my Javascript inside my HTML file:

```
//Get User ID and Trip ID in URL 

function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
{
    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
    if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
    {
        return sParameterName[1];
    }
}
}

 var userid = GetURLParameter('userid');
 var tripid = GetURLParameter('tripid');

  </script>

<script>

 //Get photos URL inside a particular Trip ID from a User ID

  var database = firebase.database();
  database.ref(`photos/${userid}/trips/${tripid}`).once('value') // 
  will return you all the photo objects inside the `tripId`
  .then(photosSnap => {
  var photosObj = photosSnap.val();
  var photosUrl = Object.keys(photosObj).map(key => 
  photosObj[key].photourl);
  // then you can return the array or use it here;


   var app = angular.module('test', []);

     app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.urls = photosUrl;

   });

console.log(photosUrl); // will be an array of all the photourls
}).catch(err => alert(err));
```

And finally my HTML which uses ng-repeat:

```
<div class="spot" ng-app="test" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="url in urls">{{url}}</li>
     </ul> 

 </div>
```

I'm using a controller with scope to loop inside my HTML with an array. So first I don't know where my error message comes from, and second I'm not sure i'm using the controller and ng-repeat properly.

Thanks

PS: I included in the head tag of my HTML file this link :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT: my Javascript inside my HTML updated (I moved everything inside the controller)

The error message is gone, my html just doesn't display any url (though the console shows there are 4 urls in my array photosUrl)

```
 <script>

  //Get photos URL inside a particular Trip ID from a User ID


var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    var database = firebase.database();
    database.ref(`photos/${userid}/trips/${tripid}`).once('value') // 
    will return you all the photo objects inside the `tripId`
    .then(photosSnap => {
    var photosObj = photosSnap.val();
    var photosUrl = Object.keys(photosObj).map(key => 
    photosObj[key].photourl);
    // then you can return the array or use it here;

    $scope.urls = photosUrl;

console.log(photosUrl); // will be an array of all the photourls
}).catch(err => alert(err));

     });

  </script>
```

Comment: photosUrl is undefined inside the scope of angular. Try to write all js within the scope of angular's module rather than writing differently in script tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nomod` is Angular's error indicating a module you've asked it to use hasn't been defined.

When you specify `ng-app`, AngularJS will automatically try to find the module you've defined with that name to load it into that block. But you're defining your module asynchronously, in the callback of a Firebase `.once()`. That callback can happen very quickly in some cases, but it's still asynchronous and won't be ready when Angular gets going here.

1. Move your `angular.module()` definition outside the Firebase callback.
2. Add `$scope.$apply()` just below setting `$scope.urls =` in the Firebase data callback.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `database` into your 'MainCtrl' controller.

Or, in a perfect world, you would abstract that logic into a seperate factory/service, and inject THAT into your controller.